# Trouble with functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, alert, opendatabase

I'm trying to figure out local caching for a project I'm working on right now and while I've had success with setting up, populating and doing most of the db side, my javascript seems to be freaking out on me.

I've made a jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/hW6RX/9/ ) to show what I mean. Clicking on Get info... should pop up an alert, then populate the default values from the db in the table, then there should be a second alert and after you clear it it should preform a few changes then add the new db values to the table (there should be 10 items total at the end, with bar and cantbelieve only showing up once and foo changing to bur the second time... pretty simple).

But, instead both popups are coming up then it only does the first printValues().  the location of the functions and alerts doesn't seem to effect the outcome (as in all the functions were inside the try, all were outside, i split them up... moved the alerts... w/e) so I'm thinking I'm missing something, or there is some kind of timing issue.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Just FYI, that second transaction is outside the try/catch, it probably shouldn't be. And just return from `js_GetDBInfo` if no DB capabilities, otherwise there's unnecessary nesting.

Comment: Sorry, the outside transaction was something that was added before the "IF NOT EXISTS" was added to the table create (which without that it would exit the transaction and no preform any code after that).  Since I have it set up so everything works first time on additional runs, it should matter anymore.  But the code still doesn't preform like I expect it to.

Comment: It works for me if I remove the `clearCache` calls; are you sure you're doing what you think you are?

Comment: Looks like I need to figure out a way to correctly clear the values on the table, because now it is just showing the edited list twice (the first run it showed the unedited list twice, then every run after shows the edited twice, I need to clear it to make it show the unedited then the edited.  Although it may just be that clearing it was allowing it to be rebuilt but the second print was happening before the changes (which is what I was thinking was happening).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed, http://jsfiddle.net/hW6RX/14/ is working as intended (although I'd rather not make the user have to click for each part of the process... but that can be fixed later I guess).

If you click Initialize it will print out the first part, and then clicking test will print out the next part (it will clear everything when you initialize or you can clear with the clear link at any time)